# Identify features of a group layer by GeoServer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, getfeatureinfo, group-layer

I encountered a strange behavior in QGIS version 3.8.1. A group layer consisting of raster, vector and PostGIS layers compiled via the GeoServer 2.15.1 is integrated as WMS into QGIS. 
If I want to identify the features at a point using QGIS, only the information for the lowest layer is displayed in the Identify Results. In the layer preview of the GeoServer all features at this point are displayed.

Does anyone know if this is an error in QGIS or requires a specific setting in QGIS or the Geoserver?

Single layers are all queryable.

Comment: QGIS as wms client uses GetFeatureInfo and expects to receive an Information in text/html format. So i guess, it depends on the server. You could try a different client to test this.

Comment: It's not an error, it's expected behaviour.  A WMS group layer is a single layer, and you should expect one result.

Comment: Okay, but then it is still confusing that the preview of the same layer in the GeoServer can distinguish the respective features, where QGIS only displays the information of the lowest layer.